# What is the benefits of RAC schedule vs responding to subscriber immediately?

Tags: reactive-cocoa

Could you clarify why RACErrorSignal is do sendError through subscriptionScheduler as shown below but not immediately calling sendError to subscriber?

```
- (RACDisposable *)subscribe:(id<RACSubscriber>)subscriber {
NSCParameterAssert(subscriber != nil);

return [RACScheduler.subscriptionScheduler schedule:^{
    [subscriber sendError:self.error];
}];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscription always happens on a scheduler. If the subscription happens on a thread that has a scheduler, such as the main thread, then that block is executed immediately. If it's not immediate, it means the subscription is being trigger from a thread that doesn't have an associated scheduler.

> To ensure consistent behavior for the `+createSignal:` and `-subscribe:` methods, each `RACSignal` subscription is guaranteed to take place on a valid `RACScheduler`.
>
> If the subscriber's thread already has a `+currentScheduler`, scheduling takes place immediately; otherwise, scheduling occurs as soon as possible on a background scheduler. Note that the main thread is always associated with the `+mainThreadScheduler`, so subscription will always be immediate there.

From: [ReactiveCocoa Design Guidelines](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/e32d77b48064e8e71e1d59cd241de054e8150180/Documentation/DesignGuidelines.md#subscription-will-always-occur-on-a-scheduler)